# Was bedeutet in der Schweiz "Sind Sie bedient"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase, dialect, swiss-standard-german

After dining in a Swiss restaurant in Bern I heard the waitresses asking

> Sind Sie bedient?

Edit:

Da es einige Konfusion gibt, möchte ich die Situation hier zunächst noch einmal ausführlich in Deutsch beschreiben.

Ich war mit einigen deutschen Arbeitskollegen in Bern und dort haben wir gemeinsam zu Abend gegessen. Nach dem Essen, als der Kollege nach der Bedienung rief, um die Rechnung zu bezahlen, fragte sie:

> Sind Sie bedient?

Aus der  Situation war klar, dass es entweder bedeutet

> Waren Sie mit dem Essen zufrieden?

oder

> Haben Sie noch einen Wunsch?

Auf jeden Fall ist die Frage für einen Deutschen überraschend.

Comment: You didn't say that she said it to *you*.

Comment: I would just like to point out as a side remark that "Are you being served?" is quite rude for a waiter to say at a restuarant after a meal.  Despite it being somewhat faithful to the literal meaning.

Comment: @Glen Wheeler: That's the point, it doesn't mean "Are you being served?". It means: "Did you get everything you wanted?".

Comment: @markus Indeed; I am more directing this at the translations below (more than one answer has "Are you being served?").

Comment: @GlenWheeler, in what way would "Are you being served?" be rude after a meal?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Upon particular encouragement, here comes my answer in German, followed by the English version:

Meine Einschätzung:

1. Die Schweizer Bedienung meinte "Möchten Sie noch etwas bestellen?". Die Formulierung "Sind Sie bedient?" ist für einen Schweizer hier nicht ungewöhnlich.
2. In einem Restaurant in Deutschland würde man sich eher wundern, was denn wohl gemeint sein mag, denn eigentlich passt die Frage hier nicht. Dort bedeutet "Ich bin bedient!", was die bejahende Antwort auf "Sind Sie bedient?" wäre, eher "Mann, ich habe genug davon", was anzeigt, dass der Sprecher nach Möglichkeit die Situation schnellstens verlassen möchte, weil er genug davon hatte und nichts mehr davon hören oder sehen möchte -- weil das, was vorher im Mittelpunkt stand, so SCHLECHT war. Der Satz "Ich habe die Nase voll" ist eine ähnliche, buntere Variation davon.
3. Andererseits: Ein Deutscher, der gefragt wird "Werden Sie bereits bedient?" könnte im Scherz antworten "Ich bin bedient -- danke", und das wäre eine humorvolle Verwendung der Phrase aus 2. Und wenn die fragende Person diesen Scherz versteht, ist diese Antwort sogar höflicher als ein einfaches "Ja, danke.".

English answer:

My 3 cents:

1. The swiss waiter/waitress meant "Is there anything else you wish to order?". This is not unusual for Swiss people.
2. In a restaurant in Germany, you´d wonder what the heck was meant, because it does not fit the situation there. In "pure" (urgh) German, "Ich bin bedient!", which would be the confirmational answer to the question "Sind Sie bedient?", means "Man I´ve got enough of this ", signaling the speaker is bailing out of the situation because he got enough and does not want to hear/see more -- because what was previously in focus was so BAD. The sentence "Ich habe die Nase voll" ("I have my nose filled up [with this crap]") is a similar, more colorfull variation.
3. On the other hand: A German being asked if he already is being served might be asked "Werden Sie bereits bedient?", and one funny reply is "Ich bin bedient -- danke", which is a humorous, or ironic, use of the phrase outlined in 2. And if the person asking understands this joke, this reply is even more polite than a simple "yes, thank you".

Comment: Magst du deine Antwort auch auf Deutsch übersetzen? Ich finde sie ist es wert.

Comment: Made it so, Sir :)

Comment: Genau. "Sind Sie bedient?" hat in der Schweiz eine finale Konnotation im Sinne von "Ist der Status Ihrer Bedientheit abschliessend befriedigend?". Wenn die Frage bejaht wird, kommt manchmal die Folgefrage "Darf ich die Rechnung bringen?". In diesem Sinne ist die Antwort von @splattne für die meisten Fälle falsch.

Answer (score 7):

It means

> Are you being served?

in the sense: *Did a[nother] waiter/waitress come to your table yet?*

Other German expressions are

> Bekommen Sie schon?

or

> Werden Sie schon bedient?

---

Btw, the expression *"Ich bin bedient!"* (colloquial) has a second, completely different meaning: *"I've had my fill!*" (in German: *"Mir genügt es!"*)

---

**Update**

This nice article confirms that it means *"Wurden Sie bereits bedient?"*:

[Schweizerdeutsch (Schwyzerdütsch): Sind Sie bedient?](http://leben-schweiz.de/schweizerdeutsch-schwyzerdutsch/)

Comment: Ich sagte `nach dem Essen`. Also wurde meine Bestellung schon ausgeführt und ich habe gegessen. Ist mein Englisch so missverständlich?

Comment: -1 for not reading the question thoroughly (didnt ever think i'd give you -1 @splattne :D)

Comment: @Samuel_Herzog and @bernd_k downvote is okay, but consider that waiters also come to the table after you're finished with the dinner to ask if you have other wishes: coffee, dessert, maybe a cigar ;)

Comment: @bernd_k your sentence is ambiguous IMHO. You didn't say that she was addressing *you*. Sorry, I interpreted it that you've heard it saying it to somebody else.

Comment: @bernd_k @Samuel Herzog: why waitress**es** then? This implies that you hear that said to other people as well. As a reply to the question asked by the waitress you could ask for the bill, add another order, or just say you're fine. That **depends** on the situation. Translating with just *"Are you happy?"* is not appropriate imo.

Comment: @splattne I didn't donw vote you. I don't think it is a polite way of communication between speakers of different native languages when it is about misunderstandings of the OP. Comments and upvotes for correct answer do as well. BTW in Germany "Wurden Sie bereits bedient?" is unusual. You will either be asked "Werden Sie schon bedient?" oder "Möchten Sie zahlen?"

Comment: @bernd_k the question itself is interesting. Did you check the link I posted? It really seems to be a Swiss "speciality" :)

Comment: +1 @splattne your answer is perfect for the titel of the question and may help people who find this question later by use of search engines. It is not the best possible for the described context and I will not accept it. I'm preparing some questions on meta, because I think the reaction of Samuel Herzog is inadequate.

Comment: away with the -1 since the link is there, very interesting, although i still feel it didnt get the point quite good.

Comment: -1 from me since the answer ignores the context given in the question, and consequently comes up with a valid answer, but for a different context (i.e., different question).

Comment: Are we creating a record of votes?  +1 from me @splattne, as per usual.  I find your answer to be quite informative.

Comment: -1 because the the answer is wrong (for most cases of usage of this phrase in Switzerland)

Answer (score 3):

I would translate it with:

> are you being served?

or

> is there anything else you would like to order?

depending on the situation.

In the clarifying edit of the question is is clear, that the latter of both translations suits best.

Comment: Does the first translation mean "has a waiter already been assigned to you?"?

Comment: @Tim: More like: Has someone already taken your order?

Comment: @tim I said **after** dinging. She asked it when she was called for the bill. I would say in high German `Waren Sie zufrieden`.

Comment: -1 for not reading the question thoroughly

Comment: @Samuel_Herzog in Takkat's (and my own) defense: *"I heard the waitresses asking"* is suggesting that *other people* were asked.

Comment: he has to edit it to get no downvote anymore. but you're right and your edit proves both of you right.

Comment: BTW one upvote to this answer is from me. Down voters please take your chance to fix your decision. I'm preparing 1 or 2 questions on meta in this context.